# Как передать управление из класса game в класс menu

Tags: java

1.Как закрыть потоки в menu.java? 
 2.Как передать управление KeyAdapter в menu.java?

Game.java

```
void go() {
    frame = new JFrame(TITLE_OF_PROGRAM + " : " + START_SNAKE_SIZE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(FIELD_WIDTH * POINT_RADIUS + FIELD_DX, FIELD_HEIGHT * POINT_RADIUS + FIELD_DY);
    frame.setLocation(START_LOCATION, START_LOCATION);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    canvasPanel = new MyCanvas();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, canvasPanel);

    //addKeyListener(getKeyAdapter());
    frame.addKeyListener(getKeyAdapter());// Добавляет упраление змейкой

    frame.setVisible(true);

    snake = new Snake(START_SNAKE_X, START_SNAKE_Y, START_SNAKE_SIZE, START_DIRECTION);

    void move() {
        int x = snake.get(0).getX();
        int y = snake.get(0).getY();
        if (direction == LEFT) { x--; }
        if (direction == RIGHT) { x++; }
        if (direction == UP) { y--; }
        if (direction == DOWN) { y++; }
        if (x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1) { x = 0; }
        if (x < 0) { x = FIELD_WIDTH - 1; }
        if (y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) { y = 0; }
        if (y < 0) { y = FIELD_HEIGHT - 1; }
        gameOver = isInsideSnake(x, y); // check for acrooss itselves
        snake.add(0, new Point(x, y));
        if (isFood(food)) {
            food.eat();
            frame.setTitle(TITLE_OF_PROGRAM + " : " + snake.size());
        } else {
            snake.remove(snake.size() - 1);
        }
    }
```

Именно в этой части не получается закрыть поток, даже убивать пытался:

```
        public void clouse() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            System.exit(0);  

        }
```

Menu.java

Закрытие потока:

```
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    game.clouse();
    }
```

В этом месте не получается закрыть поток:

```
    playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Game().go();
            new Thread().start();
            if (game == null){

            }else {
                game.clouse();


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: В чём у вас возникли затруднения с приведённым кодом?

Comment: Когда запускаю игру через menu.java, то получается так что потоки не закрываются, т.е. окна не закрываются и управление самой игры KeyAdapter не передается, хотя чисто напрямую через game.java всё работает идеально.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/766866/edit).

Comment: Хорошо, поправил.
1.Как закрыть потоки в menu.java? 2.Как передать управление KeyAdapter в menu.java?

Comment: У вас тут тонна кода. Даже смотреть лень. Вы бы сделали минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Это здесь - [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Хорошо, сделал всё